# Styling current page in ASP.NET menu

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, menu

I have master page with menu bar and a few nested pages. What is best practice to highlight selected menu item? For example:

[ Profile ] [Forum] [**Statistics**]

---

**Statistics**

blblalbla

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Do you seriousely not know about using CSS styles?

Comment: Are you asking how to know which one to highlight, or how to use CSS to give the appearance of a highlighted menu item?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use:

```
    //select menu item with matching NavigateUrl property
    foreach (MenuItem ParentMenu in menu.Items)
    {
        if (ParentMenu.NavigateUrl.ToLower() == Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath.ToLower())
        {
            ParentMenu.Selected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (MenuItem childMenu in ParentMenu.ChildItems)
            {
                if (childMenu.NavigateUrl.ToLower() == Page.AppRelativeVirtualPath.ToLower())
                {
                    childMenu.Selected = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to put the menu in a control.  You can then have properties such as `SelectedMenu` which render the style of the selected menu item.

You can read about user controls here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53.aspx

They can be a little tricky at first, but once you have got the hang of them they will be very useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

you can highlight the menuitem based on the current url.

Answer (score 0):

Use `StaticSelectedStyle` and `DynamicSelectedStyle` properties